# Android NDK does not create folders

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

I am trying to build an shared library to use in android however the build fails with the following error

> C:\workspace\AppVoice>C:\android-ndk-r8d\ndk-build.cmd all The system
>   cannot find the file specified. "Compile thumb : gsm <= add.c
>   jni/add.c:235:1: fatal error: opening dependency file
>   ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/gsm/add.o.d: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated. make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/gsm/add.o]
>   Error 1

The obj folder exists however it is empty. If I create the local/armeabi/objs/gsm folders it continues with the compile however then it fails on copying the ready .so file to the libs folder (even if I create the correct architecture folder manually there)

What can be causing the android process not to create the folders?
I am using windows xp, cygwin and android ndk r8.

The problems are both when i compile in eclipse and from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be Windows FLP (Fundamentals for legacy pcs)
it does not have the NUL device driver installed, and cygwin uses it to redirect all output to /dev/null when the device is not found the mkdir and other calls that redirect their output to null fail to execute.
Here is the fix that I did:
http://siebn.de/other/nulldevice/